# How to build Go without the literal bin, pkg, and src directories?

Tags: go, build, compilation

I am new to the Go programming language. I am hoping to integrate Go code, if possible, into existing code that contains heterogeneous code. My present organization of code is:

```
<reverse-TLD>/<component-path>/<code><extension>
```

where:

- **<reverse-TLD>** is the domain with parts reversed. For example, `com.mydomain.mysubdomain`.
- **<component-path>** is 1 or more subdirectories under which code lives. For example, `image/jpeg`.
- **<code>** is the part of a code filename before the extension. For example, `jpeg2000`.
- **<extension>** is the extension. For example, `.sh`, `.py`, etc. For example, this taken with the other elements above would have a path: `com.mydomain.mysubdomain/image/jpeg/jpeg2000.go`.

Note that code files other than Go files are in the same directory as Go files.

**My issues are:**

1. My existing structure above doesn't include **src**, **pkg**, or **bin** directories. Are there environment or Go env variables that allow me to specify these directories?
2. The directory <reverse-TLD> and all files under it is read-only. I need the output of the compilation to be based under another directory, given as `$BUILD_DIR`. That directory can have whatever directories are needed under it.
3. I am thinking that as a convention, I could use lowercase filenames for Go code that will become an executable command and leading-uppercase filenames for Go code that will become package objects. Is there a best practice naming convention for making this distinction in the Go community?
4. Is there any problem with my using reverse TLDs? For example, `com.mydomain.mysubdomain` vs. `mysubdomain.mydomain.com`.

If the **src**, **pkg**, and **bin** directories are hard requirements, then I think I'll have to write a script that finds Go files and copies them to a temporary directory that meets the requirements, compile them, and then move the built artifacts to the `$BUILD_DIR`. But, I'm hoping that Go is flexible enough to allow me to do this.

If it is possible, could you show me the commands or environment variables that are needed to compile given the constraints above? And, comments on items 1-4 above are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It is really hard to migrate the whole `GOPATH` thing into your current structure. I would suggest have a `GOPATH` and write codes there, then use soft link to link back into your current structure.

Comment: @leafbebop - using symbolic links back to the read-only source location is a good improvement. If it is not possible to configure Go building to specify the src, pkg, and bin directories, then please feel free to write up your reply as an answer.

Comment: If you want to use the go tool, you have to follow the Go conventions. You can compile and link code however you want, but it’s a lot of work, and no one else’s workflow will be compatible with yours.

Comment: @JimB - thanks... as a new Go programmer, this is the kind of advice I need. In other programming paradigms, the use of `autoconf` or other similar things is possible to guide many build aspects. Knowing the truth of things matters most and, yes, I don't want to do a lot of extra work. But, Go is not an island and needs to co-exist with other code in my case. So, I'm looking for a way that is as harmonious as possible.

Comment: If you are "new to the Go programming language" there is just one advice: Don't fight the language. Stop doing what you try to do (no idea what it is) and use Go as intended. Once you understand Go: Invoke compiler and linker yourself (see how the go tool does it by running it with -x).

Comment: @Volker - the main focus of the question is integrating Go into existing code. Btw, I'm not sure why my OP got a down vote, because the question of code integration is valid, in my opinion. It seems that Go program development does not allow the kind of integration that is possible with other programming languages. And that is fine and is part of the answer. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Why do you want to integrate with existing code? What problem are you trying to solve? This seems a lot like an XY problem (and a terrible solution).

Comment: @Flimzy - a large body of code already exists into which this will be a part. There isn't a specific problem I'm trying to solve here... I'm merely looking to integrate Go code into a larger body of existing code and looking to see if it were possible.

Comment: Then develop your Go code the Go way, until you have a problem. Then address that problem. Don't complicate things before you know what you need to fix.

Comment: The problem is one of integration.

Comment: Your Go code will produce an executable. That's true whether you do things the Go way, or your complex way. If you can integrate an executable with your complex structure, you can do it more easily the Go way.

Comment: Having to separate code into different directories means that the maintainer of code has to look in different locations for code that deals with the same topic. This makes maintenance more difficult. It would be easier if all related code were closer to each other. But, I see from the responses above that Go does not readily make this easy: having Go code alongside other code.

Comment: I really think you're abstracting/grouping at the wrong level. I've worked on many multi-langauge projects, and have never had reason to integrate multiple languages in the same directory structure, and can't imagine why I would ever want to. Maybe you have a use case that falls outside of my expertise, but it would be good to explain that in your question, if you believe you have a special case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164693/discussion-between-steve-amerige-and-flimzy).

Comment: go build have a « -o » switch to choose where to produce the executable. You can also append path to the GOPATH env variable for more place look for packages.  I set all that in a Makefile and type make to build. It’s not how go is made to works, but it works in my case. (I was already using complicate Makefile structure on the rest of the code that is in C++)

Comment: "the question is integrating Go into existing code" there is no easy way to integrate Go into other languages, you'll have a hard time calling into Go code from your Python/Ruby/C++/Haskel/Whatever code. So the question is obviously _not_ about "integrating" Go with other languages but on how to structure a multi-language project. And the only answer here is do not try to force a directory structure on Go which is unsuitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That against Go's conventions and is not a recommended practice